# Ruby class with array attribute

Tags: ruby

I have a non-database-backed class in Ruby:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :countries
end
```

I want countries to simply be an array of ISO country codes (US, GB, CA, AU, etc) and I don't want to build a separate model to hold each.  Is there a magic way to make Ruby understand that `:countries` is an array and treat it accordingly, or do I need to write the `countries` and `countries=` methods?

I tried just setting the countries array with user.countries = ['US'], and I'm getting a NoMethodError.

Comment: It's an accessor; it doesn't matter what *type* it is.

Comment: If you use `attr_accessor` this, you will get free `countries` and `countries=` :) :)

Comment: How does the class need to "treat it accordingly" that is different to just `user.countries = [:gb, :au]`?

Comment: `attr_accessor` provides the `countries` and `countries=` methods, but there is nothing to stop you setting `@countries` to something other than an array. If you want to do *array things*, like `<<` and `length` to it then you need to write your own methods.

Comment: it seems like your question is already more or less answered. But this use case that you've indicated seems more suited for a *constant* rather than an accessor method, imho.

Comment: It's not a constant because a user will actually have ownership of various countries.  I don't just need a full list of ISO codes, I need to assign ownership of those codes to a user using an array.  I could do a has_many relationship, but that's overkill for what I'm doing.

Comment: @kid_drew you will need some field in user table to store which countries he owns.

Comment: @tihom, the class has no table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *type* of a variable doesn't matter in Ruby.

`attr_accessor` just creates getter and setter methods that set and return instance variables; `@countries` in this case. You can set the instance variable to your array, or use the setter:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :countries

  def initialize
    @countries = %w[Foo Bar Baz]
    # Or...
    self.countries = %w[Foo Bar Baz]
  end
end

> puts User.new.countries
=> ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"]
```

Personally I prefer using the instance variable instead of `self.xxx`; it's too easy to forget the `self.` bit and you end up setting a local variable, leaving the instance variable `nil`. I also think it's ugly.

If the countries won't be changing between instances, why not a constant?

*Edit/Clarification*

Tadman's point is well-taken, e.g., [this diatribe on state](http://blog.voxdolo.me/a-diatribe-on-maintaining-state.html). The circumtances under which I don't care about that are limited to small, self-controlled, stand-alone classes. There are inherent risks in making those assumptions, the level of those risks is project-dependent.

Comment: Using the instance variable when you have an `attr_accessor` can lead to some slip-ups if you've overridden either of the getter or setter methods. If you do a lot of JavaScript where `this` is absolutely required, being disciplined about adding `self` isn't a big deal.

Comment: @tadman Correct. If you're using `attr_accessor` and overriding one or the other, I'd say you're doing it wrong. IMO `attr_accessor` communicates that it's an accessor, not a method that performs other logic.

Comment: Well, it could be overridden in a subclass but not in the parent class. It's kind of risky to make assumptions. If you declare any kind of accessor, you should probably use it even if the instance variable is *probably* the same.

Comment: What if I want to add elements to the array programatically? `self.countries.push("bla")` won't work

Comment: @TheRookierLearner I don't know why you think that.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like `countries` should be a constant:

```
class User
  COUNTRIES = %w(
    AF AX AL DZ AS AD AO AI AQ AG AR AM AW AU AT AZ BS BH BD BB BY BE BZ BJ BM
    BT BO BQ BA BW BV BR IO BN BG BF BI KH CM CA CV KY CF TD CL CN CX CC CO KM
    CG CD CK CR CI HR CU CW CY CZ DK DJ DM DO EC EG SV GQ ER EE ET FK FO FJ FI
    FR GF PF TF GA GM GE DE GH GI GR GL GD GP GU GT GG GN GW GY HT HM VA HN HK
    HU IS IN ID IR IQ IE IM IL IT JM JP JE JO KZ KE KI KP KR KW KG LA LV LB LS
    LR LY LI LT LU MO MK MG MW MY MV ML MT MH MQ MR MU YT MX FM MD MC MN ME MS
    MA MZ MM NA NR NP NL NC NZ NI NE NG NU NF MP NO OM PK PW PS PA PG PY PE PH
    PN PL PT PR QA RE RO RU RW BL SH KN LC MF PM VC WS SM ST SA SN RS SC SL SG
    SX SK SI SB SO ZA GS SS ES LK SD SR SJ SZ SE CH SY TW TJ TZ TH TL TG TK TO
    TT TN TR TM TC TV UG UA AE GB US UM UY UZ VU VE VN VG VI WF EH YE ZM ZW
  ).freeze
end

User::COUNTRIES.include? "US" #=> true
```

`freeze` prevents modifications:

```
User::COUNTRIES.delete "US"   #=> RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Array
```

**Update**

The problem here is that your countries array has to be persisted somehow. You are mentioning `has_many` so Rails seems to be involved. You can use `ActiveRecord`'s [`serialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize) method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :countries
end
```

This will save the `countries` attribute to the database as an object and retrieve it as such:

```
u = User.new
u.countries = ["US", "CA"]
u.save

u = User.last
u.countries
#=> ["US", "CA"]
```

It's converted to and from YAML internally, so the `users` table looks like:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM users;
+----+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | countries         | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | ---\n- US\n- CA\n | 2013-09-24 18:24:03 | 2013-09-24 18:24:03 |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: You can also make a class method to wrap this up: `def self.countries; COUNTRIES; end`. This might seem pointless, but it allows subclasses to override that method if required and avoids exposing the structure of this constant to other parts of your code that need access to an array.

Comment: See comment above.  Users should actually have ownership over a subset of the full list of ISO codes.  Has_many is overkill for my application.