# Adding elements to an array in a class programatically

Tags: arrays, ruby

Ruby newb here. I am trying to create a class that has a array as its attribute and I want to add elements to a method of the class. I don't know the elements of the array beforehand so I can't do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986081/ruby-class-with-array-attribute)

So far I have tried the following but it doesn't work

```
class Test
    attr_accessor :test_string
    def initialize
        @test_string = []
    end
    def test_if_array
        test_string << "Foobar" #doesn't work
        test_string.push("Barbaz") #doesn't work
        @test_string.push("Bla") #doesn't work
        self.test_string << "foo" #doesn't work
        self.test_string.push("bar") #doesn't work
    end
end

tester =  Test.new
p tester.test_string
```

Can anyone tell me how to push strings in the array programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call the method. Call `tester.test_if_array`

Comment: <sarcasm> I am genius </sarcasm>

Comment: It happens to the best of us! :)